# use NodeS7 package in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plc, siemens

Anyone know how to use the NodeS7 package in Typescript?
This is the package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodes7
appreciate if gives some examples to use it ?

Comment: Just do it, if you get any issue with Typescript, let solve it.

Comment: how to return the value after reading the variables' value? And as it do not have declaration file for typescript, define it as any type can work?